# Definition and properties of "Euclidean variable" in the context of pattern recognition

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry, pattern-recognition

I am reading a book on pattern recognition and I came across this term I do not understand. I did a search on the web but did not find an answer. My question sounds really trivial, my apology.

What is an Euclidean variable and which properties does this variable have?

Comment: You should provide a full quote. Most likely, the author was referring to local coordinate charts in a manifold.

Comment: You should realize that not everybody has access to this book. My suggestion is to add a full quote containing the sentence. You would have to figure out how much of the containing paragraph to copy in your question.

Comment: This is taken from Bishop " Pattern Recognition And Machine Learning" (Springer 2006), chapter 12.1.1 Maximum variance formulation

"Consider a data set of observations {x_n} where n=1,..,N and x_n is an Euclidean variable with dimensionality D"

Comment: I am sorry. I accidentally pressed "Enter".

Comment: Given what's written, the quote is just an illiterate way to say: "Let $\{x_1,...,x_N\}$ be a finite subset of ${\mathbb R}^D$." When the author says "Euclidean variable" you should read "a point in a Euclidean space." It seems that Bishop's book is simply badly written.

Comment: After looking a bit closer at the book itself, what Bishop really means that ${\mathbf x}: \Omega\to {\mathbb R}^D$ is a random variable (i.e. a measurable function from some probability space $\Omega$) and each $x_n$ is a value of ${\mathbf x}$ at some point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought there is a type of variables which I am not  aware of thus I wanted to make sure that I am understanding all the properties of those variables.